# How can I put a condition inside a data binding in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to do the following:

```
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="row in test.active">
        <div>{{ row.id }}</div>
        <div>
            {{ if (row.testTypeId == 1) { test.exams.dataMap[row.examId].name; } }}
            {{ if (row.testTypeId == 2) { test.topics.topicNameMap[row.topicId] } }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However this is giving me an error with the { inside of the {{ }}. Is there another way I could make this work?

Comment: I would suggest to keep the logic inside the controller and avoid complex expressions

Comment: I did try that with a function but then I started to get some problems with row being undefined.

Comment: Row is undefined unless you pass it into the function. See my answer below where I do just that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@jack.the.ripper is correct. Move the logic to a function in the $scope and call that instead.

```
$scope.name = function (row) {
  if (row.testTypeId == 1) {
    return test.exams.dataMap[row.examId].name;
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}
```

In the HTML:

```
{{ name(row) }}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ternary operators certainly work, [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ucGH5JaiAY5vO3sVPkhC).

```
{{ (row.testTypeId == 1) ? test.exams.dataMap[row.examId].name : '' }}
{{ (row.testTypeId == 2) ? test.topics.topicNameMap[row.topicId] : '' }}
```

Comment: They do indeed, but you definitely don't want to overuse them. Otherwise you're starting to put your code into your template.

Comment: `===` is preferred than `==`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ng-show to do this:

```
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="row in test.active">
        <div>{{ row.id }}</div>
        <div ng-show="row.testTypeId == 1">
            {{test.exams.dataMap[row.examId].name }}
        </div>
        <div ng-show="row.testTypeId == 2">
            {{ test.topics.topicNameMap[row.topicId] }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was working on the exact example, but you beat me to the punch.  This is a much better way.  It's doing it the AnugularJS way of doing declarative programming.

Answer (score 0):

Why does it need to be in the databinding itself? Couldn't you just use the `ng-if` directive?

```
<div ng-if="row.testTypeId == 1">stuff</div>
<div ng-if="row.testTypeId == 2">otherstuff</div>
```